# Highlight letters typed in the input box

Tags: jquery, highlighting

I would like to highlight the text typed in the inbox , and when its found in a table column, td, then it should highlight it, otherwise remove the highlight from it.

Here is a fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/6/ , try to type `21` in the text input, so 2 rows will be only visible, and I would like to select `21` in each `td` that is visible in the case and this is the text that was typed in the input.

I've tried many highlight scripts posted in the web, but none of them seems to work because I can not really localize the element, as this is the live query search...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a span containing only highlighted characters.
I suggest you this code:

```
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);
            var firstCell = $row.children("td:first");

            var id = $row.children("td:first").text();
            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.children("td:first").text(id);
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                firstCell.html($("").addClass("highlight").text(id.slice(0, value.length)));
                firstCell.append(id.slice(value.length, id.length));
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to customize `.highlight` rule in your CSS.

See [it live!](http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/11/)

Comment: Yea, its working fine but when if I would like to get the `td` by its `class` instead of the `:first` selector?

Comment: Your `td` does not have any `class`. If you add, for example `class="unique-id"` to your `td`, simply use `$row.children("td.unique-id")`.

Comment: Yea, but then it cut the letters intead of highlight it: http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/14/.

Comment: You can't put just `""` and add class *highlight* on it. You have to keep `<span />` in the jQuery constructor. See it: http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/15/.

Comment: Thank you :)! Could you maybe help me with adding the `.toLowerCase()` operator in there? So I could search the data case-insensitive, in case if there will be some letters.

Comment: `toLowerCase()` is indeed the function you will need. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/16/

Answer (score 0):

Like this..??

```
if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
            $row.hide();

        }
        else {
            $row.show();
            $row.css("color","red");
        }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to highlight only what the user has typed. But this could work otherwise.

Comment: No initially they will be in black,if user typed the resultant will be in the "red"

Comment: Yes, but the whole row will be red, not only "21" with the OP example.